# ROR Heroku push error Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "hashie":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting this error while pushing code on heroku. IS there anyone who can solve my problem.

```
   Resolving dependencies...
   ..Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "hashie":
   In Gemfile:
   omniauth-google (>= 0) ruby depends on
   hashie (~> 1.2) ruby
   flying-sphinx (= 0.6.2) ruby depends on
   hashie (1.0.0)
   Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
   Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
   Resolving dependencies...
   ..Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "hashie":
   In Gemfile:
   omniauth-google (>= 0) ruby depends on
   hashie (~> 1.2) ruby

   flying-sphinx (= 0.6.2) ruby depends on
   hashie (1.0.0)
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails
```

Comment: seems that the gems `omniauth-google` and `flying-sphinx` both depend on a different version of `hashie`

Comment: is `bundle install` successful on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of flying-sphinx resolves dependency problem:

```
gem 'flying-sphinx', github: 'flying-sphinx/flying-sphinx'
```